# Is there any alternative plugin for history plugin?

Tags: plugin, history

Hi，I just see that since 1.2.0， the history plugin is deprecated, and I don't know what plugin can support my requirement, because I want to get the inline actions, while the mongodb plugin seems not providing the functions.

What should I do?

Comment: last i checked, mongodb had inline actions in the transactions collections (not in blocks)

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you elaborated on what your "requirement" is as well as what "functions" are not being provided by the MongoDB plugin.

If you want to store actions to MongoDB, you could use demux to listen to the chain and then append your database of choice with the information.